# How to set two different values for same XmlElement name in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using Java 17 and Jaxb for xml parsing , the below is my sample Java class code.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {

   @XmlElement(name = "concept")
   public Concept concept;

   @XmlElement(name = "concept")
   public Concept2 concept;
}
```

In above object I will set either **concept** or **concept2** type of objects , I don't set both at a time but for both types I want xml element name as "**concept**"

Same xml element name for two different variables is not allowed so how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Couldn't you have a base abstract class that both *concept* and *concept2* objects extends ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens yes I have the base class for both concept and concept2 objects. Concept and Concept2 classes are having different fields

Comment: I think we misunderstood :) Does you have `class Concept extends BaseConcept` and `class Concept2 extends BaseConcept` ? or even implements some common interface ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Yes I have BaseConcept class but that is just empty class. Both Concept and Concept2 extends this BaseConcept class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I'd suggest to do something like the following :

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {

   @XmlElement(name = "concept")
   public BaseConcept concept;

}
```

Where `BaseConcept` is extended / implemented by both `Concept` and `Concept2` classes.

In XSD, this can be defined with the following :

```xml
<complexType name="BaseConcept" abstract="true">
...
</complexType>

<complexType name="Concept">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="tns:BaseConcept">
      <sequence>
...
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Concept2">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="tns:BaseConcept">
      <sequence>
...

      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```